# Formatting PowerShell Get-Date inside string

Tags: powershell, datetime, formatting

I can't get my head around how formatting a datetime variable inside a string works in PowerShell.

```
$startTime = Get-Date
Write-Host "The script was started $startTime"

# ...Do stuff...

$endTime = Get-Date
Write-Host "Done at $endTime.  Time for the full run was: $( New-TimeSpan $startTime $endTime)."
```

gives me the US date format while I want [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

I could use

```
$(Get-Date -Format u)
```

but I want to use $endTime to make the calculation of the timespan correct.

I have tried all permutations of `$`, `(`, `)`, `endTime`, `-format`, `u`, `.ToString(...)` and `.ToShortDate()`, but the one that works.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
"This is my string with date in specified format $($theDate.ToString('u'))"
```

or

```
"This is my string with date in specified format $(Get-Date -format 'u')"
```

The sub-expression (`$(...)`) can include arbitrary expressions calls.

Microsoft Documents both [standard and custom `DateTime` format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types).

Comment: To whit:  
Write-Output -NoEnumerate ( "The literal date is {0:d}" -f $([DateTime]::parseexact($theLiteralDate, 'yyyyMMdd', $null)));  
where the desired date format here is yyyy-mm-dd for the orignal date string literal 20180612.  Use {0:u} for sortable ISO.  The string travels through the world of DateTime and emerges back as a string in the right format.  Bypassable?
Frankly all of these are a bit of a  PITA.

Answer (score 45):

You can use the -f operator

```
$a = "{0:D}" -f (get-date)
$a = "{0:dddd}" -f (get-date)
```

---

```
Spécificator    Type                                Example (with [datetime]::now)
d   Short date                                        26/09/2002
D   Long date                                       jeudi 26 septembre 2002
t   Short Hour                                      16:49
T   Long Hour                                       16:49:31
f   Date and hour                                   jeudi 26 septembre 2002 16:50
F   Long Date and hour                              jeudi 26 septembre 2002 16:50:51
g   Default Date                                    26/09/2002 16:52
G   Long default Date and hour                      26/09/2009 16:52:12
M   Month Symbol                                    26 septembre
r   Date string RFC1123                             Sat, 26 Sep 2009 16:54:50 GMT
s   Sortable string date                            2009-09-26T16:55:58
u   Sortable string date universal local hour       2009-09-26 16:56:49Z
U   Sortable string date universal GMT hour         samedi 26 septembre 2009 14:57:22 (oups)
Y   Year symbol                                     septembre 2002
```

---

```
Spécificator    Type                       Example      Output Example
dd              Jour                       {0:dd}       10
ddd             Name of the day            {0:ddd}      Jeu.
dddd            Complet name of the day    {0:dddd}     Jeudi
f, ff, …        Fractions of seconds       {0:fff}      932
gg, …           position                   {0:gg}       ap. J.-C.
hh              Hour two digits            {0:hh}       10
HH              Hour two digits (24 hours) {0:HH}       22
mm              Minuts 00-59               {0:mm}       38
MM              Month 01-12                {0:MM}       12
MMM             Month shortcut             {0:MMM}      Sep.
MMMM            complet name of the month  {0:MMMM}     Septembre
ss              Seconds 00-59              {0:ss}       46
tt              AM or PM                   {0:tt}       ““
yy              Years, 2 digits            {0:yy}       02
yyyy            Years                      {0:yyyy}     2002
zz              Time zone, 2 digits        {0:zz}       +02
zzz             Complete Time zone         {0:zzz}      +02:00
:               Separator                  {0:hh:mm:ss}     10:43:20
/               Separator                  {0:dd/MM/yyyy}   10/12/2002
```

Comment: The MSDN pages for [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) format strings have plenty of examples, even in different languages :). +1 for suggesting format strings which is in my opinion preferrable here.

Comment: $a becomes a string, n'est-ce pas?  I needed a real string object.  The way to set the formatting first and then the value was new for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Joey, I just was not able to put my finger on these pages, so I copy paste one of my document.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) you could simply format the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) using the [`ToString("u")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#UniversalSortable) method and *concatenate* that with the rest of the string:

```
$startTime = Get-Date
Write-Host "The script was started " + $startTime.ToString("u")
```

Comment: Valid solution.  Lacks "string inside string" though.  There is no /real/ reason for me to not concatenate instead of string-inside-string.